# Spel not supported on spring annotation @Scheduled.fixedDelayString

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations, spring-el

I want to configure the `fixedDelay` in seconds in my properties file, then I want to convert it to millis in `@Scheduled` annotation.

I expected this to work:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "#{${my.scheduler.fixed.delay} * 1000}")
```

But it throw this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid
> @Scheduled method 'myMethod': Invalid fixedDelayString value "#{5 *
> 1000}" - cannot parse into integer at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processScheduled(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:384)
> ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE] at
> org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$1.doWith(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:227)
> ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]

`${my.scheduler.fixed.delay}` was correctly resolved but the expression was not resolved.

I tried to configure my own `StringValueResolver`:

```java
private static class CustomValueResolver
    implements StringValueResolver {

    private final ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    private final ExpressionParser expressionParser;

    public CustomValueResolver(final ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory, final ExpressionParser expressionParser) {

        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.expressionParser = expressionParser;
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveStringValue(
        final String strVal) {

        String value = this.beanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(strVal);
        if (value.startsWith("#{")) {
            value = this.expressionParser.parseExpression(value).getValue(String.class);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But I don't find the way to inject my custom `CustomValueResolver`.

Am I on the right or wrong way?

Comment: This is supported as of Spring Framework 4.3.RC1. Please give that a try.

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: @Normal for now I am working without SPEL, waiting for 4.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: @Normal, now working very well in 4.3.x

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
#{new Integer(${my.scheduler.fixed.delay}) * 1000}
```